# Fetch data from API and display on html JS

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to get the data from this API
https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/basic/global.json

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    
fetch('https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/basic/global.json').then((data)=>{
    return data.json();
}).then ((completedata)=>{
    
    let data1="";
    completedata.map((values)=>{
        data1=`
        <div class="output">
          <h3>Epoch</h3>
          <p>${values.epochNo}</p>
        </div>`
    });
    document.getElementById("live1").innerHTML=data1;
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
})
</script>
```

On Google console I see this error:

> TypeError: completedata.map is not a function

I don't understand where is the problem, because with the same code but this API
`https://api.coinlore.net/api/ticker/?id=257`
works fine, where is the difference?

Comment: Hi, maybe the array is wrapped in another `.data` property or something. I would suggest adding a console.log(completedata) to try and see what's the actual response you're getting from the server. It definitely sounds like completedata is not an array in your case, the logging should help.

Answer (score 0):

the API on URL https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/basic/global.json returns **object** (`{}`) and not an array (`[]`). That is why the `map` function does not exist.

Comment: hi! thanks for reply
how can fetch and display an object instaed an array?

Comment: you access it the same way as you access any other object in javascript - using 'dot' notation or 'square brackets'.
In your case for example `completedata.data.epoch.start_time`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the solution you are looking for, but it should work
:)

````js
fetch("https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/basic/global.json")
.then((res)=> res.json())
.then((res)=> console.log(res.data.epoch.start_time))```
````